# Canvas Web Application Feed Dialog

Tags: javascript, api, dialog, facebook-javascript-sdk

I am currently in the process of developing a canvas application that will make use of the social plugins provided by Facebook.

The application itself allows a user to create a text file from a form, download it if they wish and also post the file to their feed using the Feed Dialog.

I have implemented the Feed Dialog and it works fine, but the problem I am getting is that if the user clicks the cancel button from the dialog that prompts them to share the file or cancel, a message is displayed on my page stating that post was successful when it did NOT post to facebook.

How can I alter this to display a message stating that the file was not posted to their feed?

Here is the js code.

```
function postToFeed() {

                        // calling the API ...
                        var obj = {
                          method: 'feed',
                          link: 'http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
                          picture: 'http://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX',
                          name: 'Game Configuration File Creator',
                          caption: 'Call of Duty 4: Modern Warfare',
                          description: 'config_mp.cfg',
                          redirect_uri: 'https://XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX'
                        };          

                        function callback(response) {
                            document.getElementById('msg').innerHTML = 'Post was successful.';
                        }

                        FB.ui(obj, callback);
                      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to check wether the response was valid or not in your callback.

```
function callback(response) {
    if (response && response.post_id) {
      alert('Post was published.');
    } else {
      alert('Post was not published.');
    }
  }
```

Comment: @GrantDoole then accept the answer. I personally don't care if it's accepted or not if it helped, but it's common etiquette here and will help your future questions to be answered :)